# Python requests output is different to expected output

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to scrape the Generation table off the following [site](https://reneweconomy.com.au/nem-watch/).

I have the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = requests.get('http://reneweconomy.com.au/nem-watch/', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'html.parser')

table = soup.table["database table"].strip()
print(table)
```

However this code cannot find any table in the scraped page even though it is clearly there when looking through inspect.
[image: Inspect]
Could this be an issue with site not **scraping** correctly?

Thanks

Comment: Is the table generated dynamically?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I would assume so as it updates periodically.

Comment: Because that data is in an `iframe`. Try using `https://ausrealtimefueltype.global-roam.com/reneweconomy` as your URL.

Comment: this page uses JavaScript to add elements but `requests`/`BS` can't run JavaScript. You may need `Selenium` to control web browser which can run `JavaScript`.

Comment: BTW: turn off JavaScript in web brower and then load your url in web browser - you will see what `requests` can get in HTML.

Comment: It seems it reads data from API as JSON data - so you can use it to get it: https://ausrealtimefueltype.global-roam.com/api/SeriesSnapshot?time=

Comment: In addition to what @furas said about turning off JavaScript, I always write the result of the Requests call to a file so that I can see exactly what my program will have access to.

Comment: @AMC good point with saving in file - I also sometimes save HTML in file `temp.html` and use `webbrowser.open(`temp.html`)` to automatically open it in web browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page uses `JavaScript` to load data and to create table.

Using `DevTools` in Firefox/Chrome I found it load it from

https://ausrealtimefueltype.global-roam.com/api/SeriesSnapshot?time=

as JSON data

---

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

url = 'https://ausrealtimefueltype.global-roam.com/api/SeriesSnapshot?time='

r = requests.get(url,  headers=headers)
data = r.json()

for item in data['seriesCollection']:
    #for key, value in item.items():
    #    print(key, value)
    print('region:', item['metadata']['region']['name'])
    print('fuel type:', item['metadata']['fuelType']['name'])
    print('value:', item['value'])
    print('---')
```

Result

```
region: Queensland
fuel type: Black Coal
value: 5536.51307
---
region: Queensland
fuel type: Gas
value: 560.24621
---
region: Queensland
fuel type: Liquid Fuel
value: 0.0
---
region: Queensland
fuel type: Other
value: 23.9
---
region: Queensland
fuel type: Hydro
value: 18.415
---

# etc.
```

Comment: Perfect had only figured up to grabbing the json by the time you posted this!